# Crossbrowser horizontal and verticall scroll events in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to catch events for the mousewheel, touchpad (as well mac) in javascript - this horizontally and vertically - best would be giving a deltaX and deltaY. Is there a way of doing this? I found a page - http://www.thehorizontalway.com/ that seem to work on the touchpad horizontally. I require that the events are triggered without a scrollbar shown in the browser.

Until now I have not found a way to achieve this crossbrowser for horizontal and vertical. Any hints? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.adomas.org/javascript-mouse-wheel/
gives the best solution. It has been used many place including the jquery mousewheel plugin.